# Why couldn't Baez-Duarte prove the Riemann Hypothesis?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

Define 
\begin{equation} I_n=\int_{0}^{1/n} |U s_{n}(x)|^2 \mathrm{d}x
 \end{equation} where $Us_{n}(x)=\frac{1}{x}\sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{\mu(j)}{j}\rho(jx), \mu$ denotes the Mobius function and $\rho(y)$ is the fractional part of $y$. We make three crucial observations: Firstly, since $0\leq \rho(jx)\leq jx$ for every $j\geq 1, x\geq 0$, note that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \Big(\frac{\rho(jx)}{jx}\Big)<\infty$, thus the integrand of $I_n$ is *well-defined for all $x\geq 0$.* Secondly, the integral $I_n$ is defined over a *finite* range $(0, 1/n)$. Thirdly, by $2.14$ of Baez-Duarte we have $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty} Us_{n}(x)=-\frac{\sin 2\pi x}{\pi x}$ *hence $|Us_{n}(x)|<c/x$ for all $n$,* where $c$ is some positive constant. Notice that these observations *collectively* imply that $I_n \leq C$ for every positive integer $n$ where $C$ is some positive constant, or equivalently, 
\begin{equation}
\Big(\sum_{j=1}^n \mu(j)\Big)^2 = O(n),
\end{equation} by [identity 2.12 of Baez-Duarte](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=2ahUKEwjO0pP4i4vfAhWCPFAKHTh1BRkQFjABegQICBAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Folumcamp.ir%2Fmath%2Fpapers-en%2FBaez-Duarte%2520Luis%2C%2520A%2520Class%2520of%2520Invariant%2520Unitary%2520Operators%2C%2520Advances%2520in%2520Mathematics%2520144%2C%25201-12%2520(1999).pdf&usg=AOvVaw2ZIwjEUC3wZZm1CSbeVjg0) that 
\begin{equation}
I_n = \frac{1}{n}\Big(\sum_{j=1}^n \mu(j)\Big)^{2}.
\end{equation}Since it is known that the RH is equivalent to the statement that $\Big(\sum_{j=1}^n \mu(j)\Big)^2 = O(n^{1+\epsilon})$ for any $\epsilon>0$, couldn't Baez-Duarte conclude this way that the RH is true ?

Comment: Because you are mixing things you didn't look at carefully. For $x \in (0,1/n), m \le n$ then $\rho(mx) = mx$. So what ? The complicated part of $\sum_{m=1}^{n} \frac{\mu(m)}{m} \rho(mx)$ is for $x \in (1/n,1)$. Everything is explained in the paper and in several places on books, MSE and the web.

Comment: @reuns, the interval $(1/n, 1)$ is irrelevant here because our integral is over $(0, 1/n)$, $n\geq 1$.

Comment: $\int_{0}^{1/n} |Us_{n}(x)|^2 \mathrm{d}x=O\Bigg(\int_{0}^{1/n} \frac{\sin^2(2\pi x)}{\pi ^2 x^2} \mathrm{d}x \Bigg)$ doesn't make any sense. You are confusing $L^2$ and pointwise convergence. All you know is that $\sum_{m=1}^{n} \frac{\mu(m)}{m} \rho(mx)$ converges to $-\sin (\pi x)/\pi$ in $L^2([0,1])$ and under the RH it converges in $L^2([0,1], x^{-1+\epsilon})$

Comment: The paper is exactly about that, why not read it, as well as the many explications you'll find on the web.

Comment: $|Us_{n}(x)|^2 \leq \frac{C\sin^2 (2\pi x)}{x^2}$ is wrong. All you know (from the Fourier series of $\rho$ and $\sum_{d | n} \mu(d) = 1_{n=1}$ and say $\sum_n \mu(n)/n=0$ equivalent to the PNT) is that $\sum_{m=1}^{n} \frac{\mu(m)}{m} \rho(mx)$ converges to $-\sin(\pi x)/\pi$ in $L^2((0,1])$.

Comment: Nobody said that $\Big||Us_{n}(x)|^2 -\frac{C\sin^2 (2\pi x)}{x^2}\Big|<\epsilon$. As you see it implies $\Big(\sum_{m=1}^n \mu(m)\Big)^2 = O(n)$ so you could have seen it yourself... Didn't I say that studying the RH means proving a given approach cannot work ?

Comment: Pointwise convergence $\ne$ uniform convergence, otherwise analysis wouldn't exist. If it did converge pointwise (it does almost everywhere by the $L^1_{loc}$ convergence )

Comment: @reuns, i've carefully gone over your comments. It seems that you're definitely missing something. In one of your comments you said, ''nobody said $\Big||Us_{n}(x)|^2 - \frac{\sin^{2}(2\pi x)}{x^2 \pi^2}\Big|<\epsilon$  for all $\epsilon>0$ and $n\geq n_0$...'' This claim is certainly wrong, because this is **exactly** what is meant by Baez-Duarte's 2.14 that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} Us_{n}(x) = -\frac{\sin(2\pi x)}{\pi x}$.

Comment: You are claiming that in his paper on some criterion of the RH Baez is mentioning/proving that $\frac{1}{N} (\sum_{n=1}^N \mu(n))^2 = O(1)$ without noticing it ? Understanding the exact mode of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \rho(nx)$ is complicated. Showing it converges uniformly to $-\sin(2\pi x)/\pi$ is https://academic.oup.com/qjmath/article-abstract/os-8/1/313/1564796?redirectedFrom=PDF The only thing that is +/- obvious is to relate "zeta has no zeros for $\Re(s) > \sigma$" with $\sup_N \int_0^1 |\sum_{n=1}^N \mu(n)\frac{\rho( nx)}{n}x^{\sigma-3/2}|^2 dx < \infty$

Comment: @reuns, i certainly wouldn't know what was going on in an author's head when they wrote their paper. Thus i'm not claiming what you said i'm claiming.

Comment: In 2.11 he is talking of the sum, without the $1/x$ in front of it

Comment: @reuns are you **sure** you're referring to 2.11 of https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=2ahUKEwjO0pP4i4vfAhWCPFAKHTh1BRkQFjABegQICBAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Folumcamp.ir%2Fmath%2Fpapers-en%2FBaez-Duarte%2520Luis%2C%2520A%2520Class%2520of%2520Invariant%2520Unitary%2520Operators%2C%2520Advances%2520in%2520Mathematics%2520144%2C%25201-12%2520(1999).pdf&usg=AOvVaw2ZIwjEUC3wZZm1CSbeVjg0 ?

Comment: .... "On the other hand the summation on the right side of (2.11) converges
uniformly and boundedly to &(1?) sin 2?x" he is talking of the sum without $1/x$

Comment: $\sum_{m=1}^{n} \frac{\mu(m)}{m}\rho(mx)$ converges uniformly if I believe Davenport's paper, which is already complicated. Baez never claimed that $\frac{1}{x}\sum_{m=1}^{n} \frac{\mu(m)}{m}\rho(mx)$ converges uniformly nor is bounded, read again. But is this important since it is clear you don't understand what those claims imply ?

Comment: In your question the RHS is $O(1/n)$ not only $O(1)$

Comment: X-posted: https://mathoverflow.net/q/317213/91764

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your argument for "This collectively implies that $I_n\le C$ for every positive integer $n$ where $C$ is some positive constant" is based on the following reasoning: If the functions $f_n$ converge pointwise to an integrable function $f$, then $\int_{\Omega_n} f_n$ is bounded by some function of $\int_{\Omega} f$ for some $\Omega$ which contains all $\Omega_n$.

This is simply false. For example the functions $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{nx}$ converge pointwise on $(0,1)$ to $f(x)=0$. Yet $\int_0^{1/n} f_n=\infty$.

Comment: Your purported counter-example isn't valid because it doesn't satisfy **all** the outlined three observations upon which the argument is based. Note that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f_{n}(x)$ doesn't exist.

Comment: @FunIsMath. Where in your argument are you making use of continuity at zero?

Comment: @FunIsMath. I'm not sure why you think that's being used in your argument, but here's another example $f_n(x)=2nc_n$ for $x\in [1/2n,1/n]$ and $f(x)=0$ elsewhere. These functions also converge pointwise to zero and $f_n(0)=0$ for all $n$. Yet the sequence $\int_0^{c_n}f_n$ is $c_1,c_2,c_3,\dots$ and I can make that be unbounded or have any pathological property I desire.

Comment: I don't see how $2nc_n$ is a function of $x$.

Comment: It's a step function, it is constant in the interval $[1/2n,1/n]$.

Comment: And do we have $2nc_n \leq k/x$ for all $n$ where $k$ is a constant ? No we don't.

Comment: Your counter-example should satisfy all the three observations outlined.

Comment: @FunIsMath. It doesn't satisfy that inequality, but neither does your $Us_n$. Please enlighten me where it came from. Because it sure doesn't follow from the pointwise limit...

Comment: Explain how it doesn't follow

Comment: @FunIsMath. You're the one who proved it. How did you prove it? Did you accidentally assume uniform convergence instead of pointwise convergence?

Comment: @FunIsMath. Just the limit by itself tells you that for any x there is a constant $c$ which depends on x such that $f_n(x)<cf$. You seem to think that this implies that all the c's can be taken to be equal.

Comment: Doesn't the set of $c's$ have a supremum ? Note that each $c$ is finite.

Comment: The example I gave you here in the comments shows that it doesn't have to have a supremum.

Comment: You mean the invalid $2nc_n$ ? Let $C={c_{1}, c_{2}, c_3, \cdots}$. Since $0<c_i<\infty$ for each $i$, take $c= \sup C$ so that $f_{n}(x)<Cf$ for all $n$.

Comment: @FunIsMath. I'm actually super curious why you think it must have a supremum :)

Comment: You're claiming it has a finite supremum.

Comment: It certainly has a supremum since each $c_i$ is finite.

Comment: But if it is an unbounded sequence the supremum could be $\infty$.

Comment: Similarly in your question, that "positive constant c" could be $\infty$ if this is the way you are contructing it.

Comment: I'm not ''claiming'' that it has a finite supremum. Since $f(x)<\infty$, one clearly has $f_{n}(x) \leq k h(x)$ for some constant $k$ and function $h(x)<\infty$, this is the very reason that i required $f$ to be well-defined everywhere.

Comment: You're saying "there exists a positive constant such that ... <c/x". This means you are claiming that the supremum is a finite in the reasoning above.

Comment: Why shouldn't it be finite if $f(x)=O(1/x)$  ?

Comment: In other words, it's you who is claiming that a set of positive finite numbers cannot have a finite supremum !

Comment: @FunIsMath. Does $\mathbb N$ have a finite supremum?

Comment: Anyways. Here is a set of modified counter examples:  $f_n(x)=1/x$ for all $x\in (\frac{1}{n10^n}, \frac{1}{n})$ and $f_n(x)=0$ otherwise. These satisfy $f_n(x)\le 1/x$ for all x and n, they dont have bounded integrals and they converge pointwise to $f(x)=0$.

Comment: @FunIsMath. Let me know if you would like to add fourth or fifth or sixth conditions, :)

Comment: Of course one could create infinitely many functions defined piecewisely as yours, without addressing the main issues of the question. So i'm not convinced.

Comment: And what would those main issues be? I am trying to convince you that you don't have a proof.

Comment: Would it help if I made my functions continuous? Because there are standard techniques to do that too :)

Comment: @FunIsMath. We are again at the starting point. "$|Us_{n}(x)|<c/x$ for every $n$ **and** $x \in [0,1/n]$" doesn't imply anything about $\int_0^1 |Us_{n}(x)|^2dx$ which can be $\infty$. Why are you not capable to state clearly that you want $Us_n$ to converge uniformly to $-\frac{\sin 2\pi x}{\pi x}$, which is what suggests reading too fast Baez paper right after 2.11 (reading it more slowly shows they meant $x Us_n$ converges uniformly to $-\frac{\sin 2\pi x}{\pi }$, which is already a complicated theorem proven in Davenport, that I'd like to find a copy of)

Comment: @reuns, my bad, you're right. The main issue is i had overlooked the fact that $ \sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{\mu(j)}{j}\rho(jx)$ is simply $\sum_{j=1}^{n} \mu(j)$ for $x\in(0, 1/n)$, which made all of my subsequent arguments erroneous. Thanks !